# Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 1 only for one project, the rest are working fine

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, actionbarsherlock

I recently added ActionBarSherlock to my project,I only took the classes that I need. But after adding it I get this error each time I try to run the project, I HAVE TRIED CLEANING AND REBUILDING THE PROJECT FOR ABOUT 50 TIMES, AND ITS NOT WORKING FOR ME. I tried running the command "gradlew assembleDebug --info" it did not change anything, I also tried running "gradlew --refresh-dependencies" but it did not change anything. Here is the error log:

```
Error:08:29:26.024 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:29:26.025 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
08:29:26.025 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:29:26.025 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
08:29:26.025 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
08:29:26.025 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\VinceGee\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
08:29:26.026 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
08:29:26.026 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
08:29:26.026 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
```

Here is my build.gradle Module:App:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vince.empire.e_mhare"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile project(':expandablerecyclerviewer')
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

}
```

And here is my build.gradle Project:E-Mhare:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm really stuck and seriously don't know what to do from here. Please help me.

Comment: Run gradlew assemble --info to get more info.

Comment: I did that and it pointed me to my attrs.xml file which had errors....rectified them and it worked like a charm...thanks a million times